# Questions - Installing Apps on DayDream Standalone HMD

Tags: google-project-tango, virtual-reality, google-vr, tango, daydream

My questions are regarding DayDream standalone
1. Since this is an untethered VR HMD how are Apps installed? Micro USB, wireless network etc ?
Trying to find into on the Google VR Develop page, any help finding a link is appreciated.

2. The CPU is a SnapDragon in DayDream standalone are there other processors?
3. Since the DayDream standalone is Cloud AR/VR over 4G/5G network and does not require an external PC/CPU how does (a) latency and (b) game experience compare to a wireless HMD running games from a separate PC?

Answer (score 0):

daydream uses the phone in the HMD